# Angular observable post and subscribe explanation / How it works

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Explanation of Observable Post

**setup.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Post } from './model/post';
import { PostService } from './service/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'setup',
  templateUrl: './setup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./setup.component.scss']
})
export class SetupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  postUsers(input){
    this.postService.postUser(input)
      .subscribe(
        post => {
          this.post = post
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }

  clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input)
    // this.change.emit(value);
  }

  complexForm : FormGroup;
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  post: Post[];

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**post.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Post } from '../model/post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  private registerUrl = 'http://localhost:2001/api/users/register';

  postUser(user:Post) : Observable<Post[]>{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.registerUrl, user, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

**model/post.ts**

```
export class Post {
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public name: string, 
        public email: string, 
        public password: string
    ){}
}
```

I understand what the model/post.ts does, it defines the property types, what I need is clarification on the subscribe method within `setup.components.ts`. The Observable gets invoked inside `clicked()` but what I want to understand is how does this because accessible to the application so that I can proceed after the action has run its course `this.postUsers(this.input)`

Typically with a Promise I would have done the following

```
this.postUsers(this.input)
  .then(function(){
  });
```

I'd really like it if someone could explain how it works and how to achieve a confirmation that the post has completed to then run the next function

ie **I have this**

```
clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input)
    // this.change.emit(value);
  }
```

but in promise I'd do

```
  clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input)
      .then(function(){
        this.change.emit(value);
      });
  }
```

How can I get this to work with Observables? I tried to see what was returned by doing

```
  clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    const runThis = this.postUsers(this.input);
    console.log(runThis);
    // this.change.emit(value);
  }
```

but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: is there still anything unclear in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077905/2545680)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar with promises make your `postUsers` method return an observable (not a subscription)

```
postUsers(input){
    return this.postService.postUser(input);
}
```

Then you can subscribe to this method like using a `then` in promises.

```
clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input).subscribe((response)=> {
        this.change.emit(value);
    });
}
```

---

You can also convert observables into promises. Then you wouldn't get confused.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

postUsers(input){
    return this.postService.postUser(input).toPromise();
}

clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input)
      .then((res)=>{
        this.change.emit(value);
      });
}
```

Note that I haven't used the `function` keyword in my callbacks. If I did `this.change` would refer to the callbacks `change` because the `this` wouldn't refer to the component.

Answer (score 2):

> how to achieve a confirmation that the post has completed

When the stream triggers `complete` callback you will know the request has completed. This is the third callback you pass to the subscribe method or the `complete` method if you pass observer object instead of callbacks.

I think you will benefit from knowing how the operator `toPromise` work. You can then use it directly or emulate its logic. You can use it:

```
this.postUsers(this.input).toPromise()
  .then(function(){
     ...
  });
```

Basically what it does is creates a promise and returns it. Then it subscribes the the observable returned by the `this.postUsers` and waits until this observable emits `completed` event. After that, it resolves the promise with the last event it returned. Something along these lines:

```
toPromise(observable) {
   let lastReturnedValue = null;
   return new Promise() {
      observable.subscribe(
      (v)=>{
            lastReturnedValue = v;
      },
      (e)=>{
            reject(e);
      },      
      (c)=>{
            resolve(lastReturnedValue);
      });
   }
}
```

So just as with `toPromise` you can subscribe to the observable and listen for `complete` event:

```
  clicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.postUsers(this.input).subscribe(
    (v)=>{ // here you get the value and can save it },
    (e)=>{ // here you know that observable has error, similar to `catch` callback },
    ()=>{ // here you know that observable has completed, similar to `then` callback}
    );
    console.log(runThis);
    // this.change.emit(value);
  }
```

Or you can return the observable for someone else to listen:

```
  clicked(value) {
    return this.postUsers(this.input)
  }

  ...
  clicked().subscribe( // all the code from previous example)
```

Comment: I think the usage of `.then(function(){` would be a little dangerous there. `this.change.emit` will probably give a `Can't find emit of undefined` error. +1 tho :-)

Comment: @echonax, yeah, thanks, I just wanted to show the general pattern. I removed `this.change.emit` to avoid confusion. Thanks for the upvote)